# Add a column to a Spark data frame based on a group of other columns over time

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

So I'm basically trying to achieve something with my data frame. Basically I have a data frame that has a column with the timestamps in milliseconds **(MS)** and I want to create a new column that, for example, has the group that it belongs based on a step. For example, if I define a step of 180000 (3 minutes) I would want to have something like this:

[image: what I want to achieve]

So, on that example and as I want to do, I have the new column that basically has an increment of 180000 MS every time the MS gets out of that bound.

Since I'm new to Spark and Python, my first approach was to do a loop on a 180000 step and add the group after comparing the MS. The problem is that this approach is not very performant.

```python
for i in range(0, max_time, 180000):
  df = originalDf.where((originalDf['MS'] > i) & (originalDf['MS'] <= i + 180000))
  df = df.withColumn("MS_GROUP", lit(i))
```

I've checked the **groupBy** function and also tried by using a **Window** but with no luck. Is there a better option to achieve this? Many thanks.

Comment: use: [`pyspark.sql.functions.window`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=window#pyspark.sql.functions.window) with an interval of 3 minutes to create your groups. You need to convert the milliseconds to timestamp type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me know if I've understood correctly. Simply:

```
df = df.withColumn("MS_GROUP", ((originalDf['MS']/180000)+1)*180000)
```

No for loop.

Comment: exactly. Didnt knew that I could calculate inside withColumn. Also changed to to math round up. Thank you